# ¿Por qué en algunas computadoras no se ejecutan mis comandos de JAVA?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, jframe

Estoy usando NETBEANS IDE 8.0.1 y para mi proyecto final de preparatoria decidí crear una aplicación (en java) acerca de las herramientas de Windows, algo bastante sencillo, pero tengo un problema, y es que, apesar de que tengo la misma ruta para todas las aplicaciones, en algunas computadoras no abre o simplemente no ejecuta el programa, digamos, tengo 4 herramientas principales (Desfragmentador de disco, liberador de espacio, restaurar sistema y administrador de dispositivo), en mi computadora con Windows 10 se ejecutan TODAS correctamente, pero en la de un amigo para hacer una prueba solo se ejecutan 2 que es liberador de espacio y administrador de dispositivos, en resumen el problema está en que en algunas computadoras ejecuta todas las herramientas y en otras computadoras solo ejecuta algunas mi código es el siguiente:

```
public static void ADMINDISP(){
        try 
        {   
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe Start-Process 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\devmgmt.msc' -verb RunAs");
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        System.out.println(ex); 
        }
    }
```

En donde está señalada la ruta es lo mismo para todos, sólo cambia obviamente la ruta del archivo que ejecuta esa herramienta, sin embargo no entiendo por qué a algunos no les ejecuta, si hubiera otra manera de que forzara a abrir la aplicación o algo, al final llamo así para que ejecute dentro de mi botón
incluso tengo el JOptionPane donde le mostraría al usuario donde está el error al ejecutar el programa pero aún así no muestra nada, lo he probado personalmente en una pc donde falla y nada...

```
private void ADMINDISPActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        ADMINDISP();
    }
```

Dejo el link más actualizado de mi programa por si lo necesitan probar, me haría mucha utilidad saber cuál es mi error, gracias.
https://mega.nz/#!lgpgEACR!uX1n3zPepcQavDj3UXJCeThdKv27FY1PfDhsmZKSXNo

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cuando no le abre una ruta, que es lo que pasa?

Comment: Ayer logré verificar que no existen rutas, sólo hay una para todos, y ya me frustro que ponga el método o la ruta que sea a algunas computadoras les abre y a otras no, no sé a qué se deba, a mí me abren todas las herramientas, a unos cuantos amigos más también,y a otros no les ejecuta solamente el desfragmentador y el restaurar sistema, ya tengo todas las rutas, las revise bien, y nada :/, en la de mi hermano por ejemplo, pasa ese mismo error y no he encontrado solución, probé distintos métodos para que se ejecutará de diferentes maneras y nada, no sé si a lo mejor el problema sea en jframe

Comment: Seguis sin leer los enlaces que te pase, y seguis sin decirnos cual es el error.

Comment: @gbianchi ya hice los cambios, como te comentaba, al ejecutar el botón de mi interfaz se queda como cargando y de ahí no pasa, no les ejecuta ni les marca ningún error, pero a mi si me abre todas las aplicaciones correctamente, a que se podría deber?

Answer (score 0):

buenos dias. Lo mas probable es que tus variables de entorno JAVAPATH o PATH, no estén apuntando correctamente al directorio correcto donde reside tu instalación de java.

Comment: en mi caso me abren todas las rutas, pero si la pruebo en computadoras de algun amigo no le ejecuta todas las rutas, ¿cómo podría hacer que se ejecuten sin necesidad de hacer modificaciones?

Comment: Por favor mira el [tour] y tambien [answer].. Lee bien la pregunta, no tiene problemas para ejecutar su programa en JAVA..